# OfficeGen how to set column width?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am using officeGen to generate word documents.

```
<sup>  let table = [
    [
      {
        val: "TT",
        fontFamily: "Times New Roman",
      },
      {
        val: "Ten hang",
        fontFamily: "Times New Roman",
      },
      {
        val: "DVT",
        fontFamily: "Times New Roman",
      },
      {
        val: "S.luong",
        fontFamily: "Times New Roman",
      },
      {
        val: "Don gia",
        fontFamily: "Times New Roman",
      },
      {
        val: "Thanh tien",
        fontFamily: "Times New Roman",
      }],
    [1, "Cáp ngầm LS 24kv CXV/DSTA/PVC 1x95mm2", "Met", 119, "420,000", "49,980,000"],
    [2, "Cáp ngầm LS 24kv CXV/DSTA/PVC 1x95mm2", "Met", 253, "420,000", "49,980,000"],
  ];

  var tableStyle = {
    // tableColWidth: 4200,
    // tableSize: 1000,
    tableColor: "ada",
    tableAlign: "left",
    tableFontFamily: "Times New Roman",
    spacingBefor: 120, // default is 100
    spacingAfter: 120, // default is 100
    spacingLine: 240, // default is 240
    spacingLineRule: "atLeast", // default is atLeast
    // indent: 100, // table indent, default is 0
    // fixedLayout: true, // default is false
    borders: true, // default is false. if true, default border size is 4
    borderSize: 2, // To use this option, the 'borders' must set as true, default is 4
    columns: [{ width: 100 }, { width: 200 }, { width: 200 }, { width: 100 }, { width: 200 }, { width: 200 }], // Table logical columns
  };
  docx.createTable(table, tableStyle);
</sup>
```

Here is the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40f1u.png)    ],

I want the 1st col is 100, the 2nd col is 200, But it not work as i hoped
Any help?? Thanks!
//Generating word document with OfficeGen documentation

Answer (score 0):

In your tableStyle object, you're setting both `tableColWidth` and `columns`, but these properties conflict with each other.

```
const officegen = require("officegen");
const fs = require("fs");
const docx = officegen({
  type: "docx",
  pageMargins: { top: 1800, right: 1000, bottom: 1800, left: 1700 },
});

const createTable = () => {
  let table = [
    [
      { val: "TT", fontFamily: "Times New Roman" },
      { val: "Ten hang", fontFamily: "Times New Roman" },
      { val: "DVT", fontFamily: "Times New Roman" },
      { val: "S.luong", fontFamily: "Times New Roman" },
      { val: "Don gia", fontFamily: "Times New Roman" },
      { val: "Thanh tien", fontFamily: "Times New Roman" },
    ],
    [1, "Cáp ngầm LS 24kv CXV/DSTA/PVC 1x95mm2", "Met", 119, "420,000", "49,980,000"],
    [2, "Cáp ngầm LS 24kv CXV/DSTA/PVC 1x95mm2", "Met", 253, "420,000", "49,980,000"],
  ];

  let tableStyle = {
    tableSize: 24,
    tableColor: "ada",
    tableAlign: "left",
    tableFontFamily: "Times New Roman",
    spacingBefore: 120,
    spacingAfter: 120,
    spacingLine: 240,
    spacingLineRule: "atLeast",
    borders: true,
    borderSize: 2,
    columns: [{ width: 1000 }, { width: 200 }, { width: 200 }, { width: 100 }, { width: 200 }, { width: 200 }],
  };

  docx.createTable(table, tableStyle);
};

createTable();

const out = fs.createWriteStream("example.docx");

docx.generate(out, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

edit:

```
const officegen = require("officegen");
const fs = require("fs");
const docx = officegen({
  type: "docx",
  pageMargins: { top: 1800, right: 1000, bottom: 1800, left: 1700 },
});

const createTable = () => {
  let table = [
    [
      { val: "TT", fontFamily: "Times New Roman" },
      { val: "Ten hang", fontFamily: "Times New Roman" },
      { val: "DVT", fontFamily: "Times New Roman" },
      { val: "S.luong", fontFamily: "Times New Roman" },
      { val: "Don gia", fontFamily: "Times New Roman" },
      { val: "Thanh tien", fontFamily: "Times New Roman" },
    ],
    [1, "Cáp ngầm LS 24kv CXV/DSTA/PVC 1x95mm2", "Met", 119, "420,000", "49,980,000"],
    [2, "Cáp ngầm LS 24kv CXV/DSTA/PVC 1x95mm2", "Met", 253, "420,000", "49,980,000"],
  ];

  let tableStyle = {
    tableSize: 24,
    tableColor: "ada",
    tableAlign: "left",
    tableFontFamily: "Times New Roman",
    spacingBefore: 120,
    spacingAfter: 120,
    spacingLine: 240,
    spacingLineRule: "atLeast",
    borders: true,
    borderSize: 2,
    columns: [
      { width: 100 },
      { width: 200 },
      { width: 200 },
      { width: 100 },
      { width: 200 },
      { width: 200 }
    ],
  };

  docx.createTable(table, tableStyle);
};

createTable();

const out = fs.createWriteStream("example.docx");

docx.generate(out, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: I find that syntax in the github of officegen
https://github.com/Ziv-Barber/officegen/blob/HEAD/examples/make_docx.js
It couldn't be wrong

Comment: I get this error message when run your code: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cellColWidth')

Comment: Can you provide more context or specific details about how you're using OfficeGen and where this error is occurring,?

Comment: okay, check the edited code and tell me what happens

Comment: I still get this error messaage: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cellColWidth')

Comment: I have written full source code in a answer in this post, can u check for me?

Comment: Thanks for the source code, check the edited answer, I think this will work.

Comment: It still not work :((, the col width is not set as i hoped

Comment: okay, lets take a different approach , see the edited code

Comment: I've removed unnecessary properties and ensured that the columns property specifies the widths of individual columns correctly

Comment: It still not work, I think this lib have some issues with this feature. Anyway, thank u so much for your help bro

Comment: I've one solution then, Instead of defining column widths, you can set the width for each cell individually

Answer (score 0):

This is all my source code

```html
const officegen = require("officegen");
const fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
let docx = officegen({
  type: "docx",
  pageMargins: { top: 1800, right: 1000, bottom: 1800, left: 1700 },
});

const createTable = () => {
  let table = [
    [
      {
        val: "TT",
        fontFamily: "Times New Roman",
      },
      {
        val: "Ten hang",
        fontFamily: "Times New Roman",
      },
      {
        val: "DVT",
        fontFamily: "Times New Roman",
      },
      {
        val: "S.luong",
        fontFamily: "Times New Roman",
      },
      {
        val: "Don gia",
        fontFamily: "Times New Roman",
      },
      {
        val: "Thanh tien",
        fontFamily: "Times New Roman",
      },
    ],
    [1, "Cáp ngầm LS 24kv CXV/DSTA/PVC 1x95mm2", "Met", 119, "420,000", "49,980,000"],
    [2, "Cáp ngầm LS 24kv CXV/DSTA/PVC 1x95mm2", "Met", 253, "420,000", "49,980,000"],
  ];

  let tableStyle = {
    tableColWidth: 4200,
    tableSize: 24,
    tableColor: "ada",
    tableAlign: "left",
    tableFontFamily: "Times New Roman",
    spacingBefore: 120,
    spacingAfter: 120,
    spacingLine: 240,
    spacingLineRule: "atLeast",
    borders: true,
    borderSize: 2,
    columns: [{ width: 4261 }], // Table logical columns
    // columnWidths: [1000, 200, 200, 100, 200, 200], // Corrected property name
  };

  docx.createTable(table, tableStyle);
};

createTable();

let out = fs.createWriteStream("example.docx");

docx.generate(out);
```